# Is there any way to convert a .pkl file to .pb or .tflite file for use in android?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, pickle, face-recognition

I have followed this tutorial : https://github.com/abhijeet3922/Face_ID
I have used some image classes of my own to train the dataset. Now i have a .pkl file. I want to use it in android. Can anyone help me out on that please!

Comment: Yes, its possible. Read it, store it. What have you tried?

Comment: I want a way in which it can be achieved. I have the pkl file. I can read it and use it for detection and recognition, but in my PC. What steps should i take to convert it in a format that can be used in android?

Comment: Could be anything. Most boring: a *.csv file. What software are you using on Android?

Comment: E.g. for tflite there should be a function to export a numpy array. You could load pkl, then create a numpy array, then export it.

Comment: I have converted the pkl file to a numpy array but cannot find a way to convert it to tflite or pb format.

Comment: Which software will you use on Android? Is there a tf version? What is in the pkl file?